# New cs variants

Tags: expl3

In the very recent 2023-10-10 `l3kernel` update, (See: `https://www.ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel`), it looks like many new argument-specifier variants of existing control sequences were added to the kernel, mostly switching from `x` to `e` expansion variants.

I have written a package which begins with `\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[YYYY-MM-DD]`.
My package uses some of the new cs variants which were recently added without using `\cs_generate_variant:Nn`.
e.g. using `e` instead of `x` expansions for messages, `\str_set:NV`, `\msg_error:nnV`, `\keys_define:ne`, etc.

My question is:
Is it necessary for me to now write `\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2023-10-10]` instead of the previous date?
I worry that someone using an old version of LaTeX will be unable to use my package.

EDIT: Update 2023-11-11.
The 2023-11-01 kernel update added the `\IfExplAtLeastTF` command which tests the version of the LaTeX3 programming layer.
https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews38.pdf

Comment: You mean you just wrote the package in the last two days?  There is no harm in adding  `\cs_generate_variant:Nn` for the e versions that you use, by design this will silently do nothing if they already are defined in the latest format.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two aspects here: what the change means for programmers and how to check the `expl3` versions.

The team have switched from `x`- to `e`-type for a number of reasons: I've covered this in [my blog](https://www.texdev.net/2023/10/10/get-the-jag-from-x-type-to-e-type). This includes *deprecating* the `x`-type variants but not *removing* them. It will take a long time for even 'active' `expl3` developers to make the switch (if they choose to). So you can go on using the `x`-type variants 'for ever'.

That said, internally changing to `e`-type for your own functions now will be quite safe: I plan to do that for `siunitx` for example. At which point you decide to switch the core variants you use is a policy question for you: I will likely wait for TL'23 to freeze and update for TL'24.

If you want to use variants and are not sure they exist, you can always apply `\cs_generate_variant:Nn` - this is designed such that it can be called multiple times and will only generate a variant if it does not already exist.

On detecting the `expl3` version, `\NeedsTeXFormat` won't help: this checks the version of `latex.ltx`. Currently, we don't have a good interface for checking the `expl3` version, so you need something like

```
\@ifundefined{ExplLoaderFileDate}
  {\RequirePackage{expl3}}
  {}
\@ifl@t@r\ExplLoaderFileDate{2022-11-09}
  {}
  {%
    \PackageError{siunitx}{Support package expl3 too old}
      {%
        You need to update your installation of 'l3kernel'.\MessageBreak
        Loading~siunitx~will~abort!%
      }%
    \endinput
  }%
```

(again taken from `siunitx`): there is an [open issue](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/1004) about coming up with a kernel-level interface for this.

Comment: Question: Can the new `\IfExplAtLeastTF` check expl3 versions older than the release date of `\IfExplAtLeastTF`?

Comment: @User23456234 Yes, anything back to when we introduced the version data macro it uses (2016-ish I think)